# Действие по клику на слово в строке с символом @

Tags: java, android

Не могу сделать действие по нажатию на определенное слово в строке.
 Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать что-то подобное:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать библиотеку, вроде такой: [Android-TextView-LinkBuilder](https://github.com/klinker24/Android-TextView-LinkBuilder)

Или вручную сделать что-то подобное с помощью `SpannableStringBuilder`. 
Вот вопрос, аналогичный вашему: [How to click or tap on a TextView text on different words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584136/how-to-click-or-tap-on-a-textview-text-on-different-words/11438776)

Пример кода оттуда:

```
private SpannableStringBuilder addClickablePart(String str) {
    SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(str);

    int idx1 = str.indexOf("[");
    int idx2 = 0;
    while (idx1 != -1) {
        idx2 = str.indexOf("]", idx1) + 1;

        final String clickString = str.substring(idx1, idx2);
        ssb.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View widget) {
                Toast.makeText(getView().getContext(), clickString,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, idx1, idx2, 0);
        idx1 = str.indexOf("[", idx2);
    }

    return ssb;
}
```

Используем:

```
String sentence = "this is [part 1] and [here another] and [another one]";
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
textView.setText(addClickablePart(sentence), BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Вам, соответственно, нужно будет чуть-чуть изменить код, чтобы кликабельное слово не начиналось и заканчивалось с квадратных скобок, а, например, начиналось с `@` и заканчивалось пробелом.

Answer (score 1):

```
public Spannable clickableSpanByPattern(String str, Pattern pattern){
    Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(str);
    ClickableSpan clickfor;

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        clickfor = new ClickableSpan(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View p1) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };
        spannable.setSpan(clickfor, matcher.start(1), matcher.end(1),
                          Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }

    return spannable;
}
```

Пример использования:

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
    text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    text.setText(clickableSpanByPattern("test @test test@dhdj @two", Pattern.compile("\\B(@\\s*\\w+)")));
```

[image: код в работе]